# Notepad++ search and replace with current line number

Tags: command-line, notepad++, regex

I am using notepad++ and am using it to create 200 copy commands. Each line starts

```
copy \\server\\folder\a.pdf 1.pdf
```

I want the 1.pdf to be a different file name for each line so I was thinking of having the number be based on the current line number. Is this possible using regex in notepad++?

I was hoping I could do a regex find and replace where I was finding $ (end of line) and replacing it with

```
$(CURRENT_LINE).pdf
```

but current line variable is not accessible here.

Does anyone know if I can do this?

Comment: the answer provided really solves the problem of the author, but I would like to have suggested functionality in Notepad++ to be able to insert $(CURRENT_LINE) that will be replaced with real line number later

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use ALT to select column, and next navigate to edit-> column editor in order to insert increasing numbers.